# find gradient using sobel mask operator in matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient, quantization, handwriting-recognition, sobel

I am using following code to mask image using sobel mask .

```
for i=1:size(C,1)-2
    for j=1:size(C,2)-2
        %Sobel mask for x-direction:
        Gx=((2*C(i+2,j+1)+C(i+2,j)+C(i+2,j+2))-(2*C(i,j+1)+C(i,j)+C(i,j+2)));
        %Sobel mask for y-direction:
        Gy=((2*C(i+1,j+2)+C(i,j+2)+C(i+2,j+2))-(2*C(i+1,j)+C(i,j)+C(i+2,j)));

        %The gradient of the image
        %B(i,j)=abs(Gx)+abs(Gy);
        B(i,j)=sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
        direction = atan(Gy./Gx)

    end
end
```

My question is that sometimes gradient direction value is giving  as "NaN", how to avoid it?

Second, how to quantize gradient direction into eight zone and find feature vector for the image? Please someone help me.

Comment: Why don't you use BW = edge(I,'Sobel') ?? It is so simple. Second, you want to implement HOG algorithm?

Comment: using sobel technique i will get direction. using this I finally want feature vector then how can I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation :

```
clc;clear;close;

% Read the Image
image=imread('girl.png');
f=rgb2gray(image);

%   Initializations
Gx=zeros(size(f,1),size(f,2));
Gy=zeros(size(f,1),size(f,2));
Theta=zeros(size(f,1),size(f,2));
Edges=zeros(size(f,1),size(f,2));

% Sobel Filtering
for x=2:size(f,1)-2
    for y=2:size(f,2)-2

    Gy(x,y)= ( f(x-1,y+1) + 2*f(x,y+1) + f(x+1,y+1) )...
        -( f(x-1,y-1) + 2*f(x,y-1) + f(x+1,y-1) );

    Gx(x,y)= ( f(x+1,y-1) + 2*f(x+1,y) + f(x+1,y+1) )...
        -( f(x-1,y-1) + 2*f(x-1,y) + f(x-1,y+1) );   

    Theta(x,y)= atan(Gx(x,y)/Gy(x,y));  % Direction

    Edges(x,y)=sqrt( Gx(x,y)^2 + Gy(x,y)^2);

    end
end
```

Results :

[image]

Comment: This is OK thank you for this.But I want feature vector using direction and magnitude so that I can use that for supervised learning.Please tell me how to get feature vector?

Comment: What you need is a HOG descriptor, you have to create a histogram of orientations for every cell and pass that to a multi-layer neural network for training. Read this http://users.utcluj.ro/~raluca/prs/prs_lab_05e.pdf to understand the steps !!